# Universal link "apple-app-site-association" in reactJS not working

Tags: reactjs, apple-app-site-association

I am working on a reactJS web app and need to include universal links through "apple-app-site-association" file.

I've followed the steps:

(1) Create "apple-app-site-association" file with no extension
(2) Include the file inside public folder (not src)
(3) The route is --> /.well-known/apple-app-site-association)

However instead of showing the json when I link to the route, the file is directly downloaded from the web.

I think it's due to file content-type problem. Since "apple-app-site-association" file must have no extension, the server is not presenting it as application/json and is directly downladed.

Can you guys help with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you get any solution? Can you please help me out

Comment: hi @Yuyutsu! actually there wasn't any problem. Our universal links works pretty good in spite of the "apple-app-site.association" file is not presented as a json if you set the url on the browser and it directly downloaded. In our case, it doesn't matter. It works anyway.

Comment: I am getting 404 error too. But it is working for locally. My ReactJS app is deployed through aws amplify. Can you please help me 

thanks